# How can I redirect users from one url to another website that has a JavaScript action like add to cart

Tags: javascript, html, e-commerce

An example would be Website A has a product image that when you click on it, it redirects you to website B's cart page with the said product having already been added to the cart. Website B uses javascript to add to cart function. Right now I'm redirecting users to the product page which is really not good user experience.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect with JavaScript you could use
`window.location.href = "https://some url here"`

What that url would be is up to the site you want to redirect them to.

Now, if website B uses URLs to add items to the cart, you would need to replicate such a url. If it does not, and you have access to site B, you could add a listener to intercept such redirects.

Otherwise, you may need to figure out some other mechanism, such as iframe and or proxy, it would depend on site B.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location` by passing the URL of website B